# How can I extend a React Native component's props using Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, types, flowtype

I'm using Flow (`0.54.1`) on my React Native (`0.48.3`) project. I've created a component called `PrimaryButton` that wraps a native `TouchableOpacity` component. I want to type the component using some custom props and also the entire set of props for `TouchableOpacity`.

How can I access / extend the props belonging to `TouchableOpacity`? (or any native / built-in React Native component)

In the following example, I'm trying to work out how to populate `PROPS_FROM_TOUCHABLE_OPACITY`.

```
type Props = PROPS_FROM_TOUCHABLE_OPACITY & {
    title: string,
};

const PrimaryButton = ({ title, ...rest }: Props) => (
    <TouchableOpacity {...rest}>
        <View>
            <Text>{title}</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

*Component simplified for brevity*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$PropertyType` to obtain the type of some property of an object. You can then define your `Props` type like this:

```
type Props = $PropertyType<TouchableOpacity, 'props'> & {
    title: string,
};
```